# Angularjs error, Module 'testApp' is not available

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<title></title>
<meta name="author" content="Stanislau">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
            {{Message}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js code

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.Message = '123';
});
```

Error:
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'testApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=testApp

if code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<title></title>
<meta name="author" content="Stanislau">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
            {{Message}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.Message = '123';
});
```

The error is the same!!

Test version address: http://zadanie.salesdep.by/

Comment: It is working in my browser. Can you open the same URL in your browser either by hard reloading or in incognito mode ?

Comment: works fine in your link

Comment: @Afimidas, clear your browser cache

Comment: What's wrong with my browser!

Comment: ty guys, incognito mode helped me!

Comment: On Chrome: "disable cache" in console network tab and you will be fine.

Comment: Okay, i can do this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is working fine.Please check the library reference path

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
            {{Message}}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.Message = '123';
});
</script>
```